# OpenGL Lighting Shader

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I can't understand concept of smaller shaders in OpenGL. How does it work? For example: do I need to create one shader for positioning object in space and then shader another shader for lighting or what? Could someone explain this to me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very complex topic, especially since your question isn't very specific. At first, there are various shader stages (vertex shader, pixel shader, and so on). A shader program consists of different shader stages, at least a pixel and a vertex shader (except for compute shader programs, which are each single compute shaders). The vertex shader calculates the possition of the points on screen, so here the objects are being moved. The pixel shader calculates the color of each pixel, that is covered by the rendered geometry your vertex shader produced. Now, in terms of lighting, there are different ways of doing it:

**Forward Shading**

This is the straight-forward way, where you simply calculate the lighting in pixel shader of the same shader program, that moves to objects. This is the oldest way of calculating lighting, and the easiest one. However, it's abilities are very limited.

**Deffered Shading**

For ages, this is the go-to variant in games. Here, you have one shader program (vertex + pixel shader) that renders the geometrie on one (or multiple) textures (so it moves the objects, but it doesn't save the lit color, but rather things like the base color and surface normals into the texture), and then an other shader program that renders a quad on screen for each light you want to render, the pixel shader of this shader program reads the informations previously rendered in the textur by the first shader program, and uses it to render the lit objects on an other textur (which is then the final image). In constrast to forward shading, this allows (in theory) any number of lights in the scene, and allows easier usage of shadow maps

**Tiled/Clustered Shading**

This is a rather new and very complex way of calculating lighting, that can be build on top of deffered or forward shading. It basicly uses compute shaders to calculate an accelleration-structure on the gpu, which is then used draw huge amount of lights very fast. This allows to render thousands of lights in a scene in real time, but using shadow maps for these lights is very hard, and the algorithm is way more complex then the previous ones.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how should I create lighting shader where I need to only call for example AmbientLight light(pos);?

Comment: @OlafSzymański What you mean is an abstraction layer. Shaders on their own aren't object oriented. What you propably want is deffered shading, and then the AmbientLight-instances either are calling the corresponding light shader program, or they are recorded in a list, and during the rendering you iterrate over this list and call the corresponding light shader at each iterration. (Depending on when you want to create these instances). The instance then fills some uniforms (like color) and then tell the gpu to render a quad on the screen at the given possition.

Comment: @OlafSzymański You may also refer to http://www.rastertek.com/tutgl40.html there are good tutorials that can explain more than I can in this small command box xD The directX tutorials there have more content, so you might want to look at them as well (DirectX and openGL aren't *that* different)

Answer (score 0):

Writing *smaller shaders* means to **separate** some of your shader functionalities in another files. Then if you are writing a big shader which contains lightning algorithms, antialiasing algorithms, and any other shader computation algorithm, you can separate them in smaller shader files (`light.glsl`, `fxaa.glsl`, and so on...) and you have to link these files in your **main** shader file (the shader file which contains the `void main()` function) since in OpenGL a vertex array can only have **one** shader program (composition of vertex shader, fragment shader, geometry shader, etc...) during the rendering pipeline.

The way of writing smaller shader depends also on your rendering algorithm (**forward rendering**, **deffered rendering**, or **forward+ rendering**).

It's important to notice that writing a lot of shader will increase the shader compilation time, and also, writing a big shader with a lot of uniforms will also slow things down...

Comment: There is no connection between the vertex array and the shader programm. The rendering pipeline can have only one shader program set at any time. However, you can process a vertex array with multiple shader programs (one after another), and you can process multiple vertex arrays with the same shader program. And I may add that "forward+" is a terrible and misleading name for the algorithm called "tiled shading", which can work both with forward and deffered shading.

Comment: I have not say that there is a connection between a vertex array and a shader program, but that a vertex array can only have one shader program at time during a rendering pipeline, ie each time you call the `render()` function you are not able to set more than one shader program to a vertex array. And it doesn't means that it is not possible to set the same shader program for multiple vertex array at the same time. And, yes... "forward+" is a terrible name... :-)

Comment: The wording "a vertex array can only have one shader program" just sounds like there would be a connection between the vertex array and the shader program, while in fact the vertex array doesn't "have" a shader program. In fact, you can even render without having a vertex array set at all, while still using different shader programs. But I guess you want to say the right, and the wording just sounds wrong :)

Comment: Oh sorry if the wording sounds wrong... I'm not a native English speaker...